# How to schedule procedure in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

I have some procedures created in Azure DWH and need to schedule to procedures daily.

Earlier we used to run them using SQL Agent but looks like thats not possible in Synapse

Comment: Is this Synapse (formerly SQL Data Warehouse) or Synapse Workspaces (Preview)? If SQLDW, then you can use Azure Data Factory (ADF) on a scheduled trigger to call the Stored Procedure. If Workspaces, then you can use the integrated pipeline (which is really ADF) to call the Stored Procedure.

Comment: This is SQLDW.Is there detail steps on how this can be achieved or is there any documentation i can follow

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Azure Synapse Analytics doesn't support scheduling stored procedures.

> Stored procs were recently released on the serverless SQL pool engine side. Synapse Studio support yet to come.

**Refer:** [Using stored procedures in Synapse SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-stored-procedures)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is possible by using Synapse Pipelines inside Azure Synapse Studio.

1. Open your Azure Synapse Analytics workspace
2. Go to Integrate activity hub
3. Create new Pipeline
4. Drag & Drop activity called: "SQL Pool Stored Procedure"
5. Select SQL dedicated pool where you would like to execute store procedure
6. Select store procedure which you would like to execute
7. Trigger the pipeline by clicking "Add trigger" and then Trigger now (for example)
8. In the Monitor activity hub you can see the results of that pipeline and stored procedure inside.

If you are having Dedicated pool (formerly known as SQL DW gen2) then you can upgrade it to Workspace lite and then follow same steps as for standard workspace above.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to schedule queries using the serverless approach on Synapse you need to use the `stored procedure` activity in the ADF pipeline.
Steps followed (with useful resources):

1. Create the serverless SQL database and connect it to your external storage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace)
2. Create and test a SQL query on the db
3. Create a stored procedure from the SQL query and save it to the db. (https://endjin.com/blog/2021/08/managing-schemas-in-azure-synapse-sql-serverless)
4. Create a ADF pipeline and select a `stored procedure` activity.
5. Create a linked service, where you link the serverless db endpoint. This endpoint can be found in the `Azure Portal` under the `Synapse workspace`. You will need to make sure of permissions on the db to enable connection.
6. In the `stored procedure` activity, link to the created linked service. The stored procedure should then be selectable.
7. Merge the feature branch to the main branch and publish.
8. Create a trigger and link it to the published pipeline.